# How do I make an iframe disapear after it got clicked once?

Tags: html, iframe, click

As the title says,I haven't realy started creating the code because I need a little help in here.Im not good at javascript or jquery scripting,I just started learning about html so I only know the basics.Now,getting back on topic.

I want an iframe disapear as soon as it's clicked but as I said I just started scripting.Anyone has any idea ?

Comment: Read up on the documentation `jQuery` click events - http://api.jquery.com/on/ Remove element from the `DOM` - http://api.jquery.com/remove/ Manipulate CSS - http://api.jquery.com/css/ there's also `addClass` and `removeClass`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do this with plain old JavaScript.  Note that clicking the page loaded inside the iframe may not call you event handler which is why I've added a border to this example (clicking the border will execute the event handler).  You may need to overlay the iframe with another element and capture the click event on the overlaid element.

```
<iframe src="http://someurl" onclick="this.style.display = 'none'" style='border: solid 10px red'></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: as per your comment.

To include jQuery, put the following in your HTML `<head></head>`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then use [this w3schools article](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_howto.asp) to learn how to attach javascript to HTML.

In your Javascript, you can use jQuery like this:

```
// Run all of the following code when our document is loaded
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // Setup an event handler. Says, when we click on an iframe, run this function
    $("iframe").on("click",function(){

      $(this).remove();//jQuery function to completely remove from DOM
      /* OR */
      $(this).css("display","none"); //jQuery function that completely hides in CSS

    };


});
```

Since you said you're new to programming HTML, you will want to read and practice JS. [Here's](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/) an introduction to JS and jQuery.

Comment: or `$(this).addClass("hidden");` - where hidden is `.hidden { display:none; }`

Comment: How do i get it to run,the script i mean.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS to do this, give your iframe an id for example call it "iframe_id" like this:- `#iframe_id.click{ display:none;}`

Comment: So,I just put it inside the <html> tags or...
I don't know how to get css to run lol.

Comment: you can find great HTML, CSS, and javascript tutorials at www.youtube.com/thenewboston